# Query adding white spaces after a month name

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle 10.

I want to select date from database in format:

```
02<sup>nd</sup> November 2013
```

Query to get above result:

```
select
replace(
    replace(
        replace(
            replace(
                to_char(to_date('02-Nov-2013','dd-Mon-yyyy'),'ddth Month yyyy')
            ,'nd','<sup>nd</sup>')
        ,'st','<sup>st</sup>')
    ,'th','<sup>th</sup>')
,'Augu<sup>st</sup>','August')
from dual
```

Above query executes fine. But it is adding more spaces to output before `year`, I am getting output like:(Instead of one space the output contains two spaces before year)

```
02<sup>nd</sup> November__2013    //underscore denotes space
```

And if date contains `August` month then output contains four spaces instead if one.

```
02<sup>nd</sup> August____2013    //underscore denotes space
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

I have found one solution, but still I am not sure why above query is adding extra white spaces to the output.

```
select
regexp_replace(
  replace(
    replace(
      replace(
        replace(
          to_char(to_date('02-Aug-2013','dd-Mon-yyyy'),'ddth Month yyyy')
        ,'nd','<sup>nd</sup>')
      ,'st','<sup>st</sup>')
    ,'th','<sup>th</sup>')
  ,'Augu<sup>st</sup>','August')
,'[[:space:]][[:space:]]*',' ')
from dual
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The longest months have length of 9. So, all months are padded with blank spaces to the right to make up 9 characters.

You can specify the [`fm`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) format model to trim the space.

```
to_char(to_date('04-May-2013','dd-Mon-yyyy'),'ddth fmMonth yyyy')
```